# How to resolve the Pageload more than one time using kendoui

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, kendo-ui

I have develop a small Kendoui app in asp.net in this i have dynamially bind the values for listview a href,it is working fine now.But my issue is

When click the listview a href link that goes to next page but it reload more than one time 
how can i prevent this page load issue.

Please help me..

Comment: PageLoad may be executed because of a _plain_ page load or a postback, you can check with IsPostBack property.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your reply i have check if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {} but it redirect i can't under stand why it is ....

Comment: Once for event handling and once for page load?

Comment: i have call all methods in pageload event ,So whaere i can check the event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PageLoad may be fired twice for many reasons (and it depends on page content/set-up), you can find more details (and an answer) here:
http://forums.asp.net/t/990627.aspx/1

Comment: Thank you Andriano it may help to me i will test it now.Thank you so much